# Permission issues when enabling mod_expires

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd

A friend requested my help for enabling mod_expires in Apache 2, It is a remote server running Ubuntu 16. He gave me access with ssh key, after logged in through terminar i run:

```
sudo su <auser>
```

then I run the command:

```
a2enmod expires
```

But i get an error saying:

```
Could not create /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/expires.load: Permission denied
```

I have been reading about a2enmod, and all it does is creating a symlink in mods_enabled from mods_avaialble/expires.load

My friend is telling me the user he gave me is root. What can be the issue?

1. Do I need to run sudo a2enmod expires? (it requests password)
2. What exactly sudo su  does? I thought it give you root access without having to give the password?
3. I remember in old times you could do "Load Module ... " in httpd.conf, is that an option?

Answer (score 1):

1.) Looks like the user that your friend provided you with does not have the permissions to execute a2enmod. You should have him add you to the sudoers.

2.) Running sudo su will allow you super user privileges (root). Having a password or no password really depends on how you have been added to sudoers and if you have been added. Refer to this example:

```
root            ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL # No Password Needed
root            ALL=(ALL) ALL #Password is needed
```

3.) Loading modules is done nowadays by using a2enmod. Please refer to [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/a2enmod.8.html) for the man pages

Comment: my friend jus told me is hosted in google cloud, do you know that could be a limitation?

Comment: I never really worked with Google Cloud.. But if it's an Ubuntu server, the questions you posted would not really yield a different answer whether it be a physical server or cloud based. For example, I administer a bunch of AWS servers but the concepts of using sudoers and permissions would be exactly the same as it would if the servers were physical servers (non-cloud).